# Problem in existence of constant $C_K$ in Theorem 6.2.2 in Esmonde and Murty's Problems in Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm having trouble in existence of constant $C_K$ in the proof of the Theorem 6.2.2 in Chapter 6. Here K is a number field of degree $n$ over $Q$, and $O_K$ is its ring of integers.

Statement of theorem and proof in this book is as follows:

Theorem 6.2.2- There exists a constant $C_K$ such that every ideal $A \subseteq O_K$
is equivalent to an ideal $B \subseteq O_K$ with $N(B) ≤ C_K$.

Proof. Suppose $A$ is an ideal of $O_K$. Let $β \in A$ be a non-zero element such
that $|N(β)|$ is minimal.
For each $α ∈ A$, by Exercise 6.1.2(Hurwitz Lemma),  we can find $t ∈ \mathbb{Z}$, $|t| ≤ H_K$, and
$w \in O_K$ such that
$|N(tα − wβ)|$ < $|N(β)|$.
Moreover, since $α, β \in A$, so $tα − wβ \in A$; and therefore, by the minimality
of $|N(β)|$, we must have $tα = wβ$. Thus, we have shown that for any $α ∈ A$,
there exist $t ∈ \mathbb{Z} $, $|t| ≤ H_K$, and $w ∈ O_K$ such that $tα = wβ$.
Let $M = \prod_{|t|≤H_K} t$,
and we have $MA ⊆ (β)$. This means that $(β)$ divides $(M)A$, and so
$(M)A = (β)B$,
for some ideal $B ⊆ O_K$.
Observe that $β ∈ A$, so $Mβ ∈ (β)B$, and hence $(M) ⊆ B$. This implies
that $|N(B)| ≤ N((M)). Take  N((M))= C_K$. Hence, $A ∼ B$. This satisfies
the requirements.\

My question is that, according to statement, constant $C_K$ must be independent of ideal $A$ we choose,  but in the proof constant $C_K$ dependes  on number $M$ which depends upon $t$ with $|t|\leq H_K$. Here we got $t$ for each $\alpha \in A$. So the constant $C_K$ depends on the ideal $A$. If we take another ideal then we get another constant $C_K$. So how we can say that there exist a constant $C_K$ which works for every ideal of $O_K$.
Please tell where I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Well,
$$N(M) = N(\prod_{|t| \leq H_K} t) = \prod_{|t| \leq H_K} N(t)$$

Since $H_K$ is independent of $A$, it is clear that $N(M) = C_K$ is independent of $A$ as well.

The authors did *not* choose just those $t$'s matching an $\alpha \in A$, but instead all of the $|t| \leq H_K$ which is how the seeming dependence is removed.